# What is breaking on the shore? The sea foam or the waves?

Tags: present-participles, attachment-ambiguity

What is breaking on the shore? The sea foam or the waves?

> We watched the sea foam made by the waves breaking on the shore.

Comment: The waves *break*, the foam *washes* [up] onto the shore. "*When large blooms of algae decay offshore, great amounts of decaying algal matter often **wash ashore**. Foam forms as this organic matter is churned up by the surf*." http://oceanservice.noaa.gov/facts/seafoam.html

Comment: If it was in fact the foam that was breaking then I would probably write the sentence as `We watched the sea foam, made by the waves, breaking on the shore.`

Answer (score 4):

It's the waves.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breaking_wave

Sometimes only context can tell how to parse the sentence. (You have to kind of know beforehand that waves can "break" at a shore, so on.)

Answer (score 2):

As the quote says, **waves** break on the shore. From the [OED](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/breaker):

> **Breaker**: A heavy sea wave that breaks into white foam on the shore or a shoal.

These waves are also called [**breaking waves**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breaking_wave).

The breaking action of the waves creates [sea foam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sea_foam).